# Remove grey area under input tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Likely a simple one but it has me stumped currently. I have an input tag (text) that strangely sets a grey background around anything within the form. There is an image below showing the issue.

[image: Input tag sets a grey background around anything within the form]

Please also see the code below:

```
<form type="submit" action="#">
    <input name="location" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="location"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success mt-2"/>
</form>
```

I am using Bootstrap 4 with no modifications.

Strangely, when inspecting using Google Chrome, Safari or Mozilla Firefox, the grey area disappears completely and the form looks exactly like it should.

When removing the submit tag the grey area disappears and any other included tag seems to get the same result, hence why I believe it is the text input causing the issue.

Any help is appreciated and if you require any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `type="form"` on the `<form>` sets the CSS `-webkit-appearance: button;`, which makes the entire form look like a button.

reboot.scss, line 359:

```
[type=reset], [type=submit], button, html [type=button] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

See [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance).

[Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) don't typically have a `type` attribute, so you might consider removing it.

Comment: I've been banging my head against a wall for a little while over this! Completely missed it!

Thanks!

Comment: I know the feeling! Happy to be your second set of eyes.